# Issue with portuguese accented letters in installers

Tags: windows, language, installer

Recently, I've ran a russian software installer, with russian letters etc...

After that, every installer that I open in my language (brazilian portuguese), appears russians characters (e.x. й к и ч ц) instead of portuguese accented letters (e.x. á é í ó õ ã ç).

For example:

- It is showing this warning:

"Informacao:

Para evitar reiniciar o sistema apуs a instalaзгo, feche todos os aplicativos Adobe antes de continuar."

- When the correct would be:

"Informação:

Para evitar reiniciar o sistema após a instalação, feche todos os aplicativos Adobe antes de continuar."

If it was only a text issue, I wouldn't care... But it changes every folder locations during installation... For example:

- It should be C:\Program Files\Adobe\Photoshop\Configurações\
- But it turns to something like C:\Program Files\Adobe\Photoshop\Configuraзгoes\

And it causes the software to bug

The language menu at Control Panel is properly configured, I don't know what to do =/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check settings for code page of non-Unicode applications. Open classic Control Panel, click "Clock, language, and region". Then click "Regional standards" and click Advanced tab. You should have Portuguese as language for applications that do not support Unicode.

Comment: It was already portuguese ;(

It seems like it's not a system issue, but an InstallShield one... Cause even when I change the whole system language to English or other, Portuguese installers keep the same issue with special characters...

I was wondering how to clean InstallShield cache or something like that...

Comment: @TLima It could be the case. InstallShield and Windows Installer packages are non-Unicode. If a wrong encoding was specified during package creation, UI could display wrong characters.

Comment: What software do you install? Does only Adobe installer have this issue? What other installers did you try?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not only Adobe installers ;(... I've just tested few installers, the majority is acting normal... The ones that had this issue was:  Photoshop 7 (the old photoshop, in portuguese), WinRAR and VLC Media Player (photoshop is InstallShield based, I'm not sure about the others)

Comment: WinRAR 5.40 Portuguese version correctly displays accented characters in its installer, yet Portuguese Brazilian version does not. However, I've got Russian as my default language for applications which do not support Unicode.

Comment: I haven't found other way, so I reinstalled Windows today and all installers are fine now... WinRAR 5.40 brazilian portuguese is showing accented characters properly... I'm sad that future visitors looking for help won't find any =/